# if $A$ is Abelian group , $B$ is subgroup of $A$ , Is $B \times A/B \cong A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

If $A$ is abelian group and $B$ is a subgroup of $A$, $B$ is normal subgroup of $A$.

Is it true that $B \times A/B \cong A$?

I ask because I was watching an online lecture from a course in abstract algebra at Harvard extension school.

And the lecturer (whose name is Peter) was taking about vector spaces and said that if $V$ is a vector space and $W$ is a subspace, then $V/W \times W \cong V$.

So the question which I thought of is: "is this true for all Abelian groups?"

Also, is there a less restricted condition on groups which will make this property hold?

Comment: Try $A=\mathbb Z/4$.

Comment: Asked earlier today: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422057/g-1-h-cong-g-2-implies-g-1-cong-h-times-g-2/422060#comment901965_422060

Comment: With vector spaces, the underlying field has no nontrivial ideals. But with abelian groups (essentially vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}$) the underlying ring $\mathbb{Z}$ has nontrivial ideals. So there are nontrivial things to factor out.

Comment: Every vector subspace $W$ is complemented in $V$. Not every subgroup $H$ of an Abelian group $G$ is complemented in (= a factor of) $G$. Typically $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

Comment: @julien , you means by " $H$ is complemented " is that there exists another subgroup $K$ such that $G = Hk$ ? so the conditions for this property to be true is that $H$ has a complement ?

Comment: Yes. If $G\simeq H\times K$, then $G/H\simeq K$. So what you are asking is: is every subgroup of an Abelian group $G$ (which is automatically normal by the way) a factor of $G$ (i.e. $G\simeq H\times K$).

Comment: Question: this is only difficult because the OP specifies $B\times A/B$, right? With $A/B \times B$ the result is true for all groups A, isn't it?

Comment: @JackM why would the order of the factors change anything?

Comment: Not strictly speaking a duplicate since the proposed duplicate doesn't require $G$ to be abelian.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Never mind - I momentarily forgot the answer I received to one of my previous questions. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409626/is-the-cartesian-product-of-groups-the-product-of-a-normal-subgroup-and-its-quot/409631#409631 (non uniqueness up to isomorphism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by DonAntonio:

We need only take $A =\mathbb Z_4$, $B = \mathbb Z_2$. Then $A/B = \mathbb Z_4/\mathbb Z_2 \cong \mathbb Z_2 = B.\;$  Clearly, $$\mathbb Z_4 \not\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 = B \times A/B $$

The same "conjecture" would fail for $A = \mathbb Z_9$ and $B = \mathbb Z_3$, for the same reason

Indeed, what we can say is that **if** $A$ is a finite abelian group, then your conjecture will hold *provided* there is no prime $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $\,|A|$.

Comment: Gets another TU from me +1

Comment: @amWhy , why does this condition about the non-existence of such $p$ imply that the property hold ? i can guess that this is related with fundamental theorm of finite abelian groups ! but can't recognize the complete connection.

Comment: @MathsLover One variant of the fundamental theorem lets you write groups as products of $p$-power order cyclic groups. If the order of the group is square-free, then there is only one way each particular $p$-power can occur.

Comment: Indeed, it relates to the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated groups. Exactly as Zach just summarized.

Comment: why if the order is square-free then there is only one way each particular $p$-power can occur ? may you clarify this more plz ?

Comment: Well, we are talking about the direct product of **two** groups here, one being a normal subgroup of the abelian group, the other the quotient group. So if the order of a group can be divided by $p^2$, say $|A| = p^2, |B| = p$, then $|A/B| = p$. Now if $A \cong \mathbb Z_{p^2}$, then $A/B \cong B \cong \mathbb Z_p$. And $\mathbb Z_{p^2}\not\cong Z_p \times Z_p$.  A similar thing will happen  $p^2$ is a factor of the order of abelian A.

Answer (score 6):

Take $\,A=C_4=$ the cyclic group of order $\,4\,$ , and take $\,B=C_2\,$ , so is

$$C_4\cong C_2\times C_4/C_2=C_2\times C_2\;\;?$$

Comment: no ,$C_4$ can't be isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$ using the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups, so under what conditions do  this property hold ?

Comment: @MathsLover For finite abelian groups, you'd get this property if no $p^2$ divided the order of the group.

Comment: @alex.jordan , can you give the reason - proof - behind  this result ?